# R - Assign class using mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the **openxlsx** package to create excel files. To format a column as US dollars, the examples say to set the class to 'currency':

```
class(df$Currency) <- 'currency'
```

However, I would like to apply this to many columns as once and repeat once for currency, once for percentage etc. That is my ultimate goal however I get there - here is what I've tried so far.

First the working example:

```
df <- data.frame(sales = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), returns = c(-5, -10, -20, 0, 0))
class(df$sales) <- 'currency'
class(df$sales)
[1] "currency"
```

Now using dplyr and mutate 
Attempt 1:

```
df %>% 
mutate_all(`class<-`(., 'currency'))
Error: Can't create call to non-callable object
```

Attempt 2:

```
df <- df %>% 
`class<-`(., 'currency') 
df
$sales
[1] 10 20 30 40 50
attr(,"class")
[1] "currency"
```

That gets much much closer to what I wanted but the output is a list and as.data.frame and as.tbl both complain there is no method for class 'currency'.

When I used the class(df$sales) <- 'currency' I was able to just change the class within the existing dataframe.

I have a feeling this is a good chance to learn more about classes (I reviewed the Advanced R section on classes but couldn't make the connection to my problem)

Comment: Define `as.currency` and use that?

Comment: Thanks Frank - I tried this early on and abandoned too soon - taking the example provided below and returning x in the function was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To echo @Frank's comment above:

```
as.currency <- function(x) {class(x) <- "currency"; x}

iris %>%   
  mutate_all(funs(as.currency(.))) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

> ```
> Observations: 150
> Variables: 5
> $ Sepal.Length <S3: currency> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, ...
> $ Sepal.Width  <S3: currency> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, ...
> $ Petal.Length <S3: currency> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, ...
> $ Petal.Width  <S3: currency> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, ...
> $ Species      <S3: currency> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this early on but didn't return x. Combined with mutate this works. I expect I can make a function to create these functions for the list of formats I want and apply each using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `purrr`, but the result can only be coerced to a dataframe if each column also inherits from `numeric` (that is, is both currency and numeric). I don't know if that's good enough for `openxlsx`.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, z=1:10)
library(purrr)
as.data.frame(map(dfr, `class<-`, c("currency","numeric")))
```

gives

```
sapply(x, class)
     x          y          z         
[1,] "currency" "currency" "currency"
[2,] "numeric"  "numeric"  "numeric"
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't even thought to use purrr to do everything at once. I'll see if openxlsx accepts this but even if not great approach.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do this using `dplyr`, but here is one way that works.

```
# list the column names
names <- colnames(df)

# loop through the columns and assign the class 'currency'
for (i in 1:length(names)){

  class(df[, names[i]])  <- 'currency'
}

lapply(df, class)
$sales
[1] "currency"

$returns
[1] "currency"
```